# min_score excluding documents with higher scores

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a trove of several million documents which I'm querying like this:

```js
const query = {
  min_score: 1,
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        {
          multi_match: {
            query: "David",
            fields: ["displayTitle^2", "synopsisList.text"],
            type: "phrase",
            slop: 2
          }
        },
        {
          nested: {
            path: "contributors",
            query: {
              multi_match: {
                query: "David",
                fields: [
                  "contributors.characterName",
                  "contributors.contributionBy.displayTitle"
                ],
                type: "phrase",
                slop: 2
              }
            },
            score_mode: "sum"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

This query is giving sane looking results for a wide range of terms. However, it has a problem with "David" - and presumably others.

"David" crops up fairly regularly in the text. With the `min_score` option this query always returns 0 documents. When I remove `min_score` I get thousands of documents the best of which has a score of 22.749.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I guess `min_score` doesn't work the way I think it does.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing value of min_score? as example 0.5 or 20.0

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I was using ```min_score``` so that when I later added some filters into the query at ```bool.filter``` it didn't return all the documents that matched the filter even with a score of zero. Turns out that ```bool.should``` in the above query needs to be ```bool.must.bool.should```. Thanks!

Comment: Yup - I tried a range of positive numbers down to 0.000001. The highest score without ```min_score``` was 22.749. I've solved the underlying problem now but I'd be interested to understand why this apparently sane looking query fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was trying to solve was that when I added some filter clauses to the above query elastic would return all the documents that satisfied the filter even those with a score of zero. That's how `should` works. I didn't realise that I can nest the `should` inside a `must` which achieves the desired effect.